# StatusBar background Color NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, android-statusbar

I hide the statusBar in a blank Project ( js , no Framework )

it works almost perfect, but there is 2 Problems:

1. when I reveal the statusBar by pulling it down, just for 300ms or so it has a white Background until it fully comes down. (Page and action-bar backgroundColor is not white)
2. statusBar will not goes back automatically up

Comment: How did you hide the status bar?

Comment: by calling from a function contains:

```var View = android.view.View;```
 ```var window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();```
```window.setStatusBarColor(0xff636769);```
 
```var decorView = window.getDecorView();```
        ```decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);```

Comment: Use `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` to auto hide status bar, but I doubt you can retain the status bar color while it's full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060423/manoj)

this solved the problem:

```sh
var decorView = window.getDecorView();

decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
);
```